# Batch file creating another file, didnt "push" ren to another file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I have problem, when trying to create batch file from batch file:

> **test.bat:**

```
echo set "newname=%%newname%: =%%" >> batchfile.bat
echo set "newname=%%newname%:‚=e%%" >> batchfile.bat
echo set "newname=%%newname%: =_%%" >> batchfile.bat
echo set "newname=%%newname%:ý=r%%" >> batchfile.bat
echo set "newname=%%newname%:ˇ=i%%" >> batchfile.bat
echo ren %1 "%%newname%% >> batchfile.bat"
```

but after executing test.bat, this is what appears in batchfile.bat

> **batchfile.bat**

```
set "newname=%~nx1" 
set "newname=%newname: =%" 
set "newname=%newname:‚=e%" 
set "newname=%newname: =_%" 
set "newname=%newname:ý=r%" 
set "newname=%newname:ˇ=i%"
```

Does anyone know where is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of your batch file is:

```
echo ren %1 "%%newname%% >> batchfile.bat"
```

The closing `"` is in the wrong place (at the end of the line).

Try the following:

```
echo ren %1 "%%newname%%" >> batchfile.bat
```